# How can I read a String using StringReader class in Java?

Tags: java, stream, stringreader

I have to read a String char by char using the String Reader Class. I have written this code:

```
String string = "Hello, World!";
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(string);

while(stringReader.ready())
{
   System.out.println(stringReader.read());
}
```

But the loop doesn't end with the end of the string, it is infinite! Why?

I tried also to do that:

```
while(stringReader.read()!=-1)
{
   System.out.println(stringReader.read());
}
```

The loop isn't infinite...but it jumps some chars...how can I read all the String?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String str = "Hello, World!";

    //Create StringReader instance
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(str);
    int c = reader.read();
    while (c != -1){
        //Converting to character
        System.out.print((char)c);
        c = reader.read();
    }
    //Closing the file io
    reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ready` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready--) tells you whether the next call to `read` won't block.

> Returns:
>   True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise.

Once you get to the end of the string, it certainly won't block; you've reached the end of the string.  With a `String`, the contents are already present; a `StringReader` should always return `true` for `ready`.

You are skipping characters when you call `read` twice per loop -- once in the `while` condition and once in the body.  Assign it to a variable instead.

```
int c;
while((c = stringReader.read()) !=  -1)
{
    System.out.println((char) c);
}
```

You can also do what you'd normally do any other kind of `Reader` -- wrap it in a `BufferedReader` so you can call `nextLine` or wrap it in a `Scanner`.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(stringReader);
```

or

```
Scanner strScanner = new Scanner(stringReader);
```